Is there such a thing as the reverse of an implication $A \implies B$? What is it?
Is there any standard/common definition of the reverse of an implication $A \implies B$? Or is this term not used?

One note claims that

Consider the implication formula $A \implies B$.
Its reverse is $B \impliedby A$. ...
By definition, the reverse of an implication means the same as the original implication itself.


@user  The reverse is $B\impliedby A$ and the converse is $B\implies A$.  These differ by the direction of the implication arrow and so have different meanings.  Don't confuse them.

@GrahamKemp: I made a typo, now corrected

Converse, Inverse, Contrapositive.


Its reverse is $B \implies A$. ...

No, it says the reverse is $B \impliedby A$..
Notice the direction of the implication arrow.  That is what is reversed.

$B\impliedby A$ means the same as $A\implies B$

"$B$ is implied by $A$" means the same as "$A$ implies $B$".

"$B$ if $A$" means the same as "$A$ only if $B$"

$\qquad\vdots$



NB  The reverse of an implication is not often used.
Mostly you will only see the symbol in metalogic, or verbose proofs.
